# Access multiple profiles from AWS SDK - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am trying to access csv files in S3 buckets of different profiles which are saved in aws credentials file. How can I write a script in AWS SDK in python to access different profiles at a time.

Something like this

```
import boto3

profile1 = boto3.<function>("profile_name1")
profile2 = boto3.<function>("profile_name2") 

bucket1 = profile1.resource("S3")
bucket2 = profile2.resource("S3")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create sessions for different profiles in the following way,

```
import boto3

session1 = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile_name1')
profile1_s3_client = session1.client('s3') // use this to access S3 for profile_name1

session2 = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile_name2')
profile2_s3_client = session2.client('s3') // use this to access S3 for profile_name2
```

Comment: is there any timeout period for session?

Comment: @Pooja Just like there isn't any timeout period for the aws cli, there is no timeout for these sessions as well. As long has you have the credentials in your config file, you are good to use these sessions.

Comment: thanks! this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 ways as shown below -

Method 1: Create a new session with the profile

```
dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='dev')
```

Method 2: Change the profile of the default session in code

```
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')
```

Method 3: Change the profile of the default session with an environment variable

```
$ AWS_PROFILE=dev
>>> import boto3
>>> s3dev = boto3.resource('s3')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define sessions with different profiles like mentioned below, wherein for each profile you will need `access_key` and `secret_key. session_token` is not required in the case of IAM User programmatic access

```py
profile1 = boto3.session.Session(
    profile_name='dev', 
    aws_access_key_id=access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    aws_session_token=session_token
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).